# jQuery .post() fails locally, but not on server 1, and fails on server 2?

Tags: jquery, html

I have rather simple jQuery call script

```
$.post("http://scoding.com/dev/est/s/test.php", {'call[]' : [$ip]}, function(data){
                    if(data == "false") {
                        alert('The IP you searched for was not found!2');
                    } else {
                        //found
                    }
                });
```

This failed on my machine(firewall), however it worked on my test server 1, and failed on server 2, firebug returns http_code 200 but shows it red? I'm not sure how a firewall can affect this as it's user side not server side? And the call is made from server to another server?

Comment: answers below point out cross-domain issues - if jsonp isn't an option you can always create a proxy on your own domain which takes a target url parameter, as long as your server can support the extra bandwidth requirements and is setup to permit curl or similar

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do ajax functions on cross domains.

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Answer (score 0):

`.post()` is unable to make cross domain calls for some very sensible security reasons.

Crossdomain communication is possible with JSONP see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/ for more information, and see an example of its usage here http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/